# correct way to use async/await with babel 6 and webpack

Tags: async-await, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I am just trying to explore async/await . When I call the function I got this in my console:

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
```

Here is my webpack.conf.js:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval',
    entry: [
         'babel-regenerator-runtime',
        './static/apps/app.jsx'
    ],
    output : {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./static/js/bundles/[name]-[hash].js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    plugins: [ 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'syntax-async-functions', 'transform-async-to-generator'],
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: { warnings: false },
            comments: false,
            sourceMap: true,
            mangle: true,
            minimize: true
    })
    ] : [new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}), new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()]
};
```

and my function:

```
export async function x() {
    return await (5 * 5);
}
```

and the called method:

```
import {x} from '../utils/pgp.js';

.....
componentWillMount(){
        console.log(x());
    }
.....
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result of `return await` will be a promise, just as your console log is telling you. To access the resolved value, you need to chain your call with `then`, or you need to be inside another async function which can resolve using await.

```
async function x () {
  return await 5 * 5
}

// using `.then`
x().then(value => console.log(value))

// inside another async function
async function main () {
  let value = await x()
  console.log(value)
}

main()
```